# GCP python sdk running dev server with https protocol

Tags: python, ssl, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine-python

```
/google-cloud-sdk/bin/dev_appserver.py --host example.com out/app_engine/
```

This commands run development server with custom domain and with custom port as according to -h parameter. but there is no way to specify an ssl domain as it gives an error when i specify like https://example.com or http://example.com is there any way to specify protocol separately. so that i can run at secure domain
thanks

Answer (score 0):

**This isn't possible at the moment**: see [here](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=960) for details.

Comment: thats why i came to stackoverflow for solution if not solution atleast direction

Comment: You can't use HTTPS with the dev server--you'll have to use HTTP locally or take a different approach. Does that help more?